Java Affine Shift Decryption
Attempting to write java code to decrypt an affine shift cypher. In testing the code outputs a correct decryption but gets the 'b' value of the key wrong.
Here is the code:
public void solve() {
    double bestSpell = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;  // Start with the worst possible spelling score
    String bestDecode = "";

    // Loop over all possible values of 'a'
    for (int a = 1; a < 26; a++) {
        int a_inv = 0;

        // Find a^-1 (the modular multiplicative inverse of a)
        for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
            if ((a * i) % 26 == 1) {
                a_inv = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        // If no valid modular inverse, skip this 'a'
        if (a_inv == 0) continue;

        // Loop over all possible values of 'b'
        for (int b = 0; b < 26; b++) {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

            // Apply decryption formula for each character in the ciphertext
            for (int i = 0; i < strippedCT.length(); i++) {
                if (strippedCT.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                    int x = strippedCT.charAt(i) - 'A';  // Convert character to 0-25 range
                    int decodedValue = (a_inv * (x - b + 26)) % 26;  // Ensure non-negative result
                    output.append((char) (decodedValue + 'A'));  // Convert back to character
                } else {
                    output.append(' ');
                }
            }

            // Check the spelling score
            double currentSpell = sc.spellCheck(output.toString());

            // Update best found key if this one is better
            if (currentSpell > bestSpell) {
                bestA = a;
                bestB = b;
                bestDecode = output.toString();
                bestSpell = currentSpell;
            }
        }
    }

    // Output the best results
    System.out.println("Solved as mono");
    System.out.println("A: " + bestA + " B: " + bestB);
    System.out.println(bestDecode);
    this.plaintext = bestDecode;
}

I have tried including more error handling to prevent negative values and impossible values of 'a' however this has not changed the outcome so I am wondering if someone who has more experience with these kinds of cypher could help point out the logic error.

I tried to look at this but I haven't found the problem yet. Can you tell me how you know that the b value that you get is incorrect?
